# Rhapsody C: Preserved parts in the generated code

Tags: rhapsody

I need to mark some parts in the generated code to be edited manually and not been overwritten when make a re-generation.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the following annotation

```
/*#[ preserve*/
...
/*#] preserve*/
```

in a non microC project as mentioned in this [link](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21632630)